# How does one get a parameter from a params (pytree) in haiku? (jax framework)

Tags: jax, haiku

For example you set up a module and that has params. But if you want do regularize something in a loss what is the pattern?

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax
def loss(params, x, y):
   l = jnp.sum((y - mlp.apply(params, x)) ** 2)
   w = hk.get_params(params, 'w') # does not work like this
   l += jnp.sum(w ** w)
   return l
```

There is some pattern missing in the examples.

Comment: It looks like there is a `params.keys()` that  you can look at and just access the items in the dict that way. I'm not sure if this is the "official" pattern for stuff like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` is essentially a read-only dictionary, so you can get the value of a parameter by treating it as a dictionary:

```python
print(params['w'])
```

If you want to update the parameters, you cannot do it in-place, but have to first convert it to a mutable dictionary:

```python
params_mutable = hk.data_structures.to_mutable_dict(params)
params_mutable['w'] = 3.14
params_new = hk.data_structures.to_immutable_dict(params_mutable)
```